# Indentation in html textarea with spaces doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, text, textarea

When i'm trying to add extra spaces to html textarea to make my text be indented and wrapped in a right way I need, textarea trims these spaces and wraps text in it's own way.

Lets assume that dot (.) is a space. In this case things go in a way, I want them. The line `'....some.........texts........here'` will be displayed in text area of size (cols: 13) with monospace font as:

[image]

here we have a string in text area of max 13 chars length. And the string indented with one tab that represented with 4 chars at the beginning. So there are additional dots at the end of the lines, to make next part of string be on the next line in text area. And it works.

But if I use spaces instead of these dots, so the initial line is:

```
'    some         texts        here'
```

in the same text as before it will look like

[image]

So textarea trimmed additional spaces in all places where it wrapped the string. Is there any way to avoid it?

UPD: Looks like this topic is highlighted [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4842781306519552).

Comment: can you show whatever you tried?

Comment: i've tried to use &nbsp somehow, and to play with 'white-space' css property but with no effect